# How is the user id image generated on SO?

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, identicon

I am a little curious about the cute little kaleidoscopic images associated with each user on this site.
How are those generated? Possibilities are:

1. A list of images is already there in some folder and it is chosen randomly.
2. The image is generated whenever a user registers.

In any case, I am more interested in what kind of algorithm is used to generate such images.

Comment: I believe the question is referring to the images (identicons) used when the user doesn't have a gravatar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called an [Identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).  If you entered and e-mail, it's a based on a hash of your e-mail address.  If you didn't enter an e-mail, it's based on your IP address.

Jeff [posted some .NET code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/identicons-for-net/) to generate IP based Identicons.

Answer (score 5):

Its usually generated from a hash of either a user name, email address or ip address.

Stackoverflow uses [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) to do the image generation.

As far as I know the idea came from [Don Parks](http://www.docuverse.com/blog/donpark/2004/05/03/secure-ui-9-block-phishmarks), who writes about the technique he uses.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, it's generated from an IP address.

"IP Hashing" I believe it's called.

I remember reading about it on a blog; he made the code available for download. I have no idea where it was from, however. :(

Answer (score 1):

The images are produced by Gravatar and details of them are [outlined here](http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/04/22/identicons-monsterids-and-wavatars-oh-my/), however, they do not reveal how they are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the images are a 4×4 grid with the upper 2×2 grid repeated 4 times clockwise, just each time rotated 90 degrees, again clockwise. Seems the two colours are chosen randomly, and each 1×1 block is chosen from a predefined set.

EDIT: obviously my answer was ad hoc. Nice to know about identicons.

Try this: http://www.docuverse.com/blog/9block?code=(32-bit integer)8&size=(16|32|64)

substituting appropriate numbers for the parenthesized items.

Answer (score 0):

I bet each tiny tile image is given a set of other tile images it looks good with. Think of a graph with the tiles as nodes. You pick a random node for the corner and fill it's adjacent spots with partners, then rotate it and apply the same pattern four times. Then pick a color.

Instead of a graph, it could also be a square matrix in which each row represents an image, each column represents an image, and cell values are weights.